# Django Python - select column from related_object in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I just started with Django, and trying to figure out how stuff works. I'm stuck with the following problem.

I have a models.py:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    land = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Naam(models.Model):
    kort = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    middel = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='namen')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lang
```

I have a view.py:

```
def index(request):
    all_stations = Station.objects.all()
    return render(request,'stations/index.html', {'all_stations' : all_stations})


def detail(request, station_id):
    try:
        station = Station.objects.get(id=station_id)
        stationnamen = station.namen.values()
    except Station.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("station does not exist")
    return render(request, 'stations/detail.html', {'stationnamen' : stationnamen.values()})
```

In a template html I'm trying to show some details about a station (kort,middel,lang) names. Is it possible to show a particular field in the queryset like:

```
<h1>{{ stationnamen.kort }}</h1>
```

In the shell I'm able to do this as follows:

```
station1.namen.values('kort')
```

How this work in template files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values

You need to loop on this QuerySet to get dict object. This dict object will contains all your field.

`station1.namen.values('kort')`

Here you just filter the field **kort**. Your queryset contains dict with only **kort** information.

> The values() method takes optional positional arguments, *fields, which specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited. If you specify the fields, each dictionary will contain only the field keys/values for the fields you specify. If you don’t specify the fields, each dictionary will contain a key and value for every field in the database table.

```
{% for namen_dict in stationnamen %}
   # used namen_dict to display what you want. It's a dict.
{% endfor %}
```

Like say Daniel Roseman, you don't need `values()` to access information about Naam object. Why are you using `values()` ?

**Final solution base on your need (see comments)**

**view.py**

```
def index(request):
    all_stations = Station.objects.all()
    return render(request,'stations/index.html', {'all_stations' : all_stations})


def detail(request, station_id):
    try:
        stationnamen = Station.objects.get(id=station_id).namen.all() # Don't need station object.
    except Station.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("station does not exist")
    return render(request, 'stations/detail.html', {'stationnamen' : stationnamen})
```

**template**

```
{% for naam in stationnamen %}
    <h1>{{ naam.koort }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ naam.middel }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ naam.lang }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ naam.station }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Solution if you have a **one-to-one relationship** like you except

```
def detail(request, station_id):
    try:
        naam = Naam.objects.get(station_id=station_id) # Only one Naam object.
    except Station.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("station does not exist")
    return render(request, 'stations/detail.html', {'naam' : naam})
```

template (don't need for loop)

```
<h1>{{ naam.koort }}</h1>
<h1>{{ naam.middel }}</h1>
<h1>{{ naam.lang }}</h1>
<h1>{{ naam.station }}</h1>
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I just wanted the 'kort' , 'middel'  value in the template. Like:

<h1>{{ station.namen.kort}}</h1>
    <h1>{{ station.namen.middel}}</h1>
    <h1>{{ station.namen.lang}}</h1>

Why is a FOR statement required? And what in case there is just a one-to-one relationship? In that case a FOR seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: Hum you are using ForeignKey. So it can be many-to-one. If you want a one-to-one relationship, you need to used https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

You wan to display all the field. So in your case, values it's not good. You need to used Daniel solution. Get queryset of Naam object.

Comment: Great reply!  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your use of `values`. That's for the rare occasion when you want to get dictionaries, but most of the time you just want to pass the actual model instance.

```
   station = Station.objects.get(id=station_id)
   stationnamed = station.namen.all()
   ....
   return render(request, 'stations/detail.html', {'stationnamen' : stationnamen})
```

The other thing to understand is that there are *many* instances of Naam for each Station, so you need to iterate through them in your template.

```
{% for naam in stationnamen %}
    {{ naam.koort }}
{% endfor %}
```